# return ModelState instead of view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a basic login method where i check if the Email with which the user logs in, exists in the database:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Users model)
{
    using (var db = new MySqlContext())
    {
        if (db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Email) == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Email doesn't exist");
            Return SOMETHING
        }
     }
}
```

As you can see, i have written `Return SOMETHING`, and really, what i would want, is to just return the ModelError to my loginform instead of a view.

Fyi, in my view (which is a modal) i have a standard `Validationsummary` like this:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
```

Comment: why do you not want to return a view?  what are you trying to do?

Comment: Wouldn't you typically just `return View(model);`? The model state dictionary is passed to the view and the validation errors will be shown.

Comment: @juunas exactly

Comment: Ok, well. I get your point @juunas the thing is, The login form resides inside a modal, which means, that if i return ActionResult("modal", "home)" then it doesn't render it on top of my _layout page, because its renderpartial.

Comment: Use Ajax with RenderPartial or JsonResult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't return a View, what would be shown behind the modal? You're going to have to return a View of some sort. (if you handle validation like [this](http://timgthomas.com/2013/09/simplify-client-side-validation-by-adding-a-server/) which is my preferred approach, this will be taken care of because you never actually leave the page).

To show the model's error messages on the modal you're going to have to relaunch the Modal when validation fails.

On whatever view you return you're gonna have to check if the Model State is valid and relaunch the Modal.

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //relaunch you're modal. 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! i get your point. Read juunas answer instead. i Think it makes better sense to return a JsonResult in this case?